# how we can convert image and text in pdf when button click?

Tags: android

I'm making an android app and this app one image view and one text view and one button. how make like that i click button when image and text make pdf and save our device file manager?

Comment: Please try to write a more clear question, include what code you have already, and please, leave out all the "dear"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the following code to create pdf -

```
implement these following libraries in your build.gradle app section: 

implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:io:7.0.0'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:layout:7.0.0'
```

Then you need to write the following code on button click -

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          try {
                 createPDF();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
       }
});
```

Then create method createPDF()

```
private void createPDF() throws Exception{

        File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AppName" + File.separator + "FolderName");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
            success = docsFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            String randCode = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()); //used for unique file name eveytime
            randCode = randCode.replaceAll(":", "");
            randCode = randCode.replaceAll(" ", "");
            pdfFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(), randCode + ".pdf");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4); //Page  Size
            document.setMargins(30,30,30,30); //here you can put any margin numbers as you wish
            document.open();

            imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            imageView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            imageView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            image.scaleToFit(document.getPageSize().getWidth(), document.getPageSize().getHeight());
            image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);//Center,Left,Right another options
            document.add(image);
            document.newPage(); //used for creating new page
            Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);
            document.add(new Paragraph("HeadingIfNeeded", f));

            Font f1 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            document.add(new Paragraph("\n\n" + TextView.getText().toString(), f1));

            document.close();
        }else {
            showToastRed("Error");
        }
}
```

You can use the above code to createPDF.